# Is there an isdate PHP function?

Tags: php, date, if-statement

I saw an inbuilt function called isdate in the user function below and when I checked the PHP documentation I didn't find it. Does it exist and what does it do; or is this simply a typo?

```
function mystery($a, $b, $c) {
$result = null;
if (strlen(trim($a)) == 0) {
    $result = $c;
}
else {
    if (strtolower(trim($b)) == "n") {
        if (!is_numeric($a)) {
            $result = $c;
        }
        else {
            $result = trim($a);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (strtolower(trim($b)) == "d") {
            if (!isdate($a)) {
                $result = $c;
            }
            else {
                $result = trim($a);
            }
        }
        else {
            $result = $a;
        }
    }
}
return($result);
}
```

Comment: Well your title is wrong - there is no loop there at all...

Comment: True John31316, no loops here. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, this isn't really an answer since I don't know what the original function is for and to be honest I don't care. Whatever, you can do several simplifications to make it more readable, to avoid duplicate processing, the useless `$result` variable and in particular to remove these unreadable nested if/else, in other words to remove all this useless noise:

```
function mystery($a, $b, $c) {
    $trima = trim($a);

    if ( empty($trima) )
        return $c;

    $b = strtolower(trim($b));

    if ( $b == "n" )
        return is_numeric($trima) ? $trima : $c ;

    if ( $b == "d" )
        return isdate($trima) ? $trima : $c ;

    return $a;
}
```

I hope this will help you to understand what this function is supposed to do *(perhaps a context will be helpful)*.

Comment: I get your frustration Casimir et Hippolyte. This is I think a bad question to test someone with.